# Can the new Famo.us Library be used without require?

Tags: physics, famo.us, famous-engine

I'm talking about the library here: http://famous.org/

It uses require() methods and I was curious if there's a different version with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a cdn build of the Famous Engine you can use the `famous` global variable (currently version 0.6.2).

`http://code.famo.us/famous/0.6.2/famous.min.js`

You can access the `FamousEngine` as follows:

`var FamousEngine = famous.core.FamousEngine`;`

*NOTE:* This is a complete build of the full library and will not give you the benefit of module loading and building only your required components into your bundles. This will cause your app to take longer to load.